# Do the lower part of underwears (panties, boxers, etc.) have a name?

Tags: single-word-requests

The term "lower part of panties" is common according to [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?ei=K6xgWtT-GMbO0gTCp4zIBw&q=%22lower%20part%20of%20her%20panties%22&oq=%22lower%20part%20of%20her%20panties%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1158.1920.0.2037.7.7.0.0.0.0.142.609.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.0.0....0.ZuVrnNQ2WGQ). Is that how it's commonly referred? Or the part under an underwear has a name?

Comment: Are you just asking what we call the small undergarment worn on the legs, or are you talking about the lowermost portion of that garment?

Comment: @tchrist The lowermost portion of the garment (where the crotch rests).

Comment: I would have called it the gusset, but as only the Urban Dictionary backs me up on that one, I'll just leave it as a comment for future viewers who are not of a nervous disposition!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Judging by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panties), we call it simply "the crotch":

> [image]

Comment: _My crotch is stuck in my crotch._ Metonymy gone mad.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - You're getting awfully crotchety.